# P trap for 2 drains?

Tags: plumbing

I am remodeling my bathroom and hopefully move my washer dryer. my goal is to share the new shower drain with the washing machine drain. do i need 2 separate p traps or can these 2 drains share a p trap.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Under IPC (and probably other codes) anything other than "a double sink" with various short distance restrictions on what constitutes that requires its own trap.

https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2018/chapter-10-traps-interceptors-and-separators

1002.1 for the detailed language, but the short and sweet is you might be able to share a vent, but each needs its own trap.

Furthermore (under UPC, apparently not a problem under IPC) you are not allowed to put a laundry P-trap under (or within 6" of) the floor, which would work against sharing with any normal shower drain.

Comment: Thank God for codes because if you shared the trap, every time the washer drained, the water would back up into the shower. +1